# How to push message/event into a message queue from somewhere with no direct access?

Tags: c++, event-loop

I have a forever-run event loop in a multithreaded program, a lot of functions and methods will push messages to this event loop. A simplified version:

```
class EventLoop {
public:
    void run();
private:
    std::deque<std::string> m_msg_queue;
    std::condition_variable m_q_cv;
    std::mutex m_q_mtx;
};

void EventLoop::run() {
     while(true) {
         //use m_q_cv to wait for data in m_msg_queue and dispatch
     }
}

int main() {
    EventLoop el;
    el.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this approach correct? If so, what's the best way to enqueue events in other functions/methods other than main()?
I don't like doing `extern Event el` in other .cpp files...

Answer (score 2):

Define a contract for posting or sending messages into the event loop and to react to received events. A typical API would expose at least the send/post pair of procedures plus some kind of contract for the messages and a mechanism for hooking up callbacks. Then expose this contract instead of your implementation which might stay hidden inside of a library.

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example of the `contract`? Wnat's the difference between a `post` and a `send` if both of them enqueue *event*? I guess I need to somehow leverage the kqueue() since I'm working in freeBSD

Comment: Have a look at one of the event-driven APIs, if you really have to roll your own, Boost.Asio, Microsoft's Async Agents integrated into PPL or similar. Post/Send usually let you "enqueue" a message asynchronously or synchronously...

Answer (score 1):

Define your `EventLoop` in a header and include that in other files that need it to get the definition.

Then give the classes that need it references or non-owning pointers to the `EventLoop` instance you created in `main()`. Those can be passed in constructors or set via setter methods for example.

No need to have anything global here.

When you have a large number of classes you can also just have them inherit from a common base class that handles your event processing, a bit like this:

```
class EventSource {
    EventLoop* _eventLoop;
protected:
    // Puts a message on the message queue of the event loop.
    void sendMessage(std::string message);
public:
    EventSource(EventLoop *eventLoop);
}

class Subclass : public EventSource {
public:
    Subclass(EventLoop* loop);
}
```

You'd still pass the pointer to the constructor of your subclasses but the base class is responsible for the actual communication.

Comment: So, you are suggesting pass `EventLoop&`, right? Then I'm afraid the reference has to be passed through a lot of functions/methods. It is a solution, but is there a better one?

Comment: You can just make it a private field in the classes that need it and access it from the methods in those classes. Then you would only pass it to the constructors of the classes that use it.

Comment: That only simplifies the code in a *very* simple program. What if I have 20 (maybe even nested) classes which all contain methods need to push event to `EventLoop el`?

Comment: You could for example derive them all from a common base class that gives you methods to push events to the loop.

Comment: That sounds really good to me now. +1! Would you mind to modify your answer to indicate that? I want to see what others think of this approach.